# Render onclick attribute using react.js when calling renderComponentToStaticMarkup

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let us say I have a react component that will render to static html server side. Certain elements will have onsubmit and onclick attributes that will not be handled by react but should still call a javascript function. In this particular case I would like to generate a contact form server side but the client will need to load up recaptcha:

```
var contactForm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var recaptcha_id = "recaptcha_div";
    return(
        <div className="contact pure-form">
          <h4 className="boxedTitle">Contact Form</h4>
          <form key="form" method="POST" action=".">
          <fieldset key="sender_email">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input name="sender_email" placeholder="Your Email" type="email" />
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset key="subject">
            <label>Subject</label>
            <input name="subject" placeholder="Subject" type="text" />
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset key="message">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"/>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset key="humanity">
            <div id={recaptcha_id}></div>
            <input ref="captcha_btn" type="button" value="Show reCAPTCHA" onClick={"showRecaptcha('"+recaptcha_id+"');"}></input>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset key="submit">
            <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Send"/>
          </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
    )
  }
});

console.log(React.renderComponentToStaticMarkup(contatForm()))
```

But onClick is not rendered. I tried a few other things that did not work:

- tried onclick attribute, not rendered
- supplied componentDidMount which manually set the attribute on the DOM node, but this isn't called when rendering static markup

Answer (score 6):

I've hit the same issue. My solution was to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html)

```
 <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `
    <button onClick="alert('hello')" >Detalii</button>
  `}} 
 />
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 2):

onClick doesn't accept strings.  You need to pass it a function.  Normally, you could do `onClick={window.showRecaptcha.bind(null, recaptcha_id)}`.

This won't work with renderComponentToStaticMarkup, of course.  You'll have to bind the event using JavaScript (external or inline `<script>` tag), or do something hacky, or not use react.  The `<script>` tag with addEventListener is probably the best solution here.

Strings of JavaScript have been considered a bad practice for over 5 years now.  This includes onclick, etc. in html, eval, setTimeout/setInterval with a string, and probably some I'm forgetting.  Even when rendering markup, it's not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem because I have JS inserted into the DOM after component is rendered. I solved this with some clues from previous answers and came up with this:

```
wrapper_function(){
   //function i want in my onclick attribute
   window.myFunc();
}
render() {

   return(
      <img className="openbtn" onClick={this.wrapper_function.bind(this)} src="..."/>
```

Actually an even easier way is just assign the onclick listener in the client side JS